# Dependency injection is only for testing?

Tags: php, dependency-injection

I read many times that hardcoding object is not a good practice:

```
class Session
{
    private $user;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new User();
    }
}
```

its bad only because of its untestable behaviour? I simply find this hardcoding easier to read. Of course I can add those methods to be DI-like:

```
    public function setUser (User $userObj)
    {
        $this->user = $userObj;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
```

But then its like a house where even the trussing can be changed. What for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike a house, which is a physical object and where the trussing *can't* be changed, this is code, wherein things are less permanent.

To be honest, having used DI for years I think it's overused. Quite simply: a bunch of a class's dependencies *won't* change, and if they do,it's easy enough to *then* apply DI to them.

Sticking with the house analogy, my position is becoming "don't necessarily build the entire house extension now, but also don't build a load-bearing wall where a door might need to go". I'd create your dependency objects in your constructor, so if it ever becomes necessary to make them swapabble, it's easy enough to add a constructor arg and start passing the dependency in via a DI framework if needs must.

One thing you're leaving yourself open for then is that every instance where that class is created will then need to be replaced with a DI-friendly version, which means a lot of refactoring, and accordingly a lot of regression testing. This is a heavy risk. If you make sure you've got very thorough automated test coverage, a lot of this risk is mitigated.

On the other hand... using a DI framework from the outset, even if the dependencies aren't injected immediately, it'll still mitigate this consideration even more, when it comes time to need to inject them.

Using DI certainly *does* make your testing a lot easier, which in turn will increase your ability to achieve higher test coverage. But I also don't think one should code *specifically* for testing.

So there's a few things to weigh-up and apply to your specific style and requirements when making this decision.